# Styling Spinner3D select row view borders

Tags: codenameone

I have an app that renders CN1 LightWeight picker properly on low-res devices, namely some low-end Android devices but getting weird behavior on iPhone 7 plus upward, even on the simulated version.

I have tried styling the **Spinner3DRow** in GUI Builder but this doesn't fix the issue.

When the Spinner is pressed to spin, the text and the middle borders disappear and re-appear after releasing (sometimes). See the image below for reference:

**December** and lines are missing.

[image]

The app is also newly published in store and could be downloaded on the iPhone 7 plus upward for reference [here](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/red-trucks/id1469687463).

How do I style these lines and the text to always remain visible regardless of the device resolution and keep the behavior consistent?

**Edit:**

On testing again, the issue is occurring even on low-res devices.

Comment: This issue seems to be a regression related to this: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2852